# Appium Python WebDriverWait wait.until(expected_conditions.alert_is_present()) random failure

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, appium-ios, webdriverwait

I have a Appium test class testing an iOS app with two nearly identical tests inside:

```
def test_fail(self):
    self.log_in('invalid_user_1')
    self.wait.until(expected_conditions.alert_is_present())
    alert = self.driver.switch_to.alert
    assert "Your mobile number is not registered with us" in alert.text
    alert.accept()

def test_normal(self):
    self.log_in('empty')
    self.wait.until(expected_conditions.alert_is_present())
    alert = self.driver.switch_to.alert
    assert 'Please enter mobile number' in alert.text
    alert.accept()
```

When I run the test, *test_fail* (it runs first before *test_normal*), it would always fail to catch the warning dialog with error:

> WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: An attempt was made to operate on a modal dialog when one was not open.

The *test_normal works though. I tried to comment out *test_normal*, the *test_fail* would fail with the same message.

I then try to comment out *test_fail*, but this time *test_normal* would work. So for some strange reason, *test_fail* just won't work with `self.wait.until(expected_conditions.alert_is_present())`

However, if I replace the *test_fail* test wait.until line:

```
self.wait.until(expected_conditions.alert_is_present())
```

with:

```
self.wait_for('OK')
```

Then everything would work.

The self.wait is declared in the the def setUp(self) `self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 120)`

I'm running Appium 1.7.2 (Appium GUI 1.4.0) on Mac OS X. The test iOS is run on iPhone 7 simulator with OS 11.2.

The error stack trace:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 331, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/Users/steve/Desktop/Temp/Appium/Ding_ios_aws/ios_aws/tests/test_invalid_login.py", line 16, in test_invalid_user_login
    self.wait.until(expected_conditions.alert_is_present())
  File "/Users/steve/venv/Appium/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "/Users/steve/venv/Appium/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 387, in __call__
    alert = driver.switch_to.alert
  File "/Users/steve/venv/Appium/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/switch_to.py", line 55, in alert
    alert.text
  File "/Users/steve/venv/Appium/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/alert.py", line 69, in text
    return self.driver.execute(Command.GET_ALERT_TEXT)["value"]
  File "/Users/steve/venv/Appium/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/steve/venv/Appium/lib/python2.7/site-packages/appium/webdriver/errorhandler.py", line 29, in check_response
    raise wde
WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: An attempt was made to operate on a modal dialog when one was not open.
```

Can anyone help me figure out what's going on?

test_normal dialog screen image
[image: image of the dialog of test_normal]

test_fail dialog screen image
[image: image of the dialog of test_fail]

Comment: could you share the screenshots of both the alerts?

Comment: @NaveenKumarRB Hi, I have updated the with the screen shots

Comment: the error is thrown after waiting for 120 seconds or immediately?

Comment: @NaveenKumarRB immediately. I did try to add another "self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 120)" in test_fail to try to reset the wait (not sure if that's how it works though), but it didn't help.

Comment: Could you add complete stack trace? I think the error is in `alert = self.driver.switch_to.alert`. try adding 1-2 seconds sleep before this and try.

Comment: @NaveenKumarRB I've updated the stack trace into the post.

Comment: @NaveenKumarRB adding sleep before "alert = self.driver.switch_to.alert" did not help, but adding it before "self.wait.until(expected_conditions.alert_is_present())" works. I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are facing the bug https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/10286.

Bug:
In the first ping/check of alert itself, if alert is not present, Appium throws the exception without waiting for the given time.

This bug is recently logged (15 days before). try latest version. I think it is fixed in latest version beta.

Also refer https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent/issues/857, which says it is Appium issue but not WebDriver.

Temporary Solution:
Add 1-3 seconds sleep to make sure alert is present before checking for the explicit condition.

Comment: Thank you. I also just found this link about 30 minutes ago. It's exactly the problem. I then try to catch WebDrierException and add a sleep(1) and retry the wait.until(expected_conditions.alert_is_present()), and it works.